# get ip address of web user

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation

are there any free web services out there that will detect the IP Address of the user accessing your site, and then give you information like zip code, and local?

I am using C# on VS2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to get the IP?

I believe you can use http://www.ip2location.com/

Comment: Man I should have done better research on this before posting my question.  I see someone already posted the same question as I did.

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store that database of IPs locally, you could use [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csharp), it has a C# API and a free IP->location database (and more accurate paid one).

Check [this old SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service) for some web services.